# Excel cell value needs to be updated in a SharePoint List using Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, excel, power-automate

I have a document library in which there are different folders which contains excel files. Excel file has name SA_0012ABCD_201901_Report. So here the 0012 is the folder name. So we Match the excel file name with the folder name and move them inside folders using flow. After that the properties needs to be filled to the columns. The excel file inside contains a cell which has value of amount. That cell value need to be updated to the Column Amount outside. So whenever a file is uploaded, the excel cell value k39 needs to be updated to the column amount of the list. I want this to be done using a Power Automate flow.

Comment: Not sure I understood the requirements correctly; could you show an example of **Column Amount outside**? Possibly show the structure of the Document Library. It's possible to update Excel Table using Power Automate, but not sure about where the outside value is located at? Are you uploading Excel files manually or using Power Automate?

Comment: We are uploading them manually. I meant the files we upload is excel . The excel has a cell k39 that cell value has to be uploaded into the column amount . This functionality shuld be done using power automate.

Comment: That means - flow needs to read Excel value from cell k39 and then update the meta data column of the library named as [Amount] with value in k39, right? I think flow reads from a [Table] in Excel. Do these Excel files have tables in them?

Comment: No they don't have tables in it .

Comment: Please see my response. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm providing a Power Automate sample that can be used to do:

1. Read value from a cell in the Excel file uploaded to a SPO library
2. In order to read values from an Excel file in Power Automate, the Excel file needs to have a table. The Power Automate first checks for a Table (Table1), if it doesn't find it, it creates it for a specific range containing the data.
3. Update Document meta data, in this case, [Amount], with the value read from the Excel Cell.
4. To avoid *File Locked For Shared Use* for recently created files in SPO library, a delay mechanism implemented when updating the meta data of the excel file. You can read details at [here](https://www.timlinenterprises.com/power-automate-file-lock-fail/)

### Row Excel File

[image]

### MS Flow (Power Automate)

[image]

### Detail 1

[image]

### Detail 2

[image]

```
outputs('List_rows_present_in_a_table')?['body/value']?[37]['K']

Note: Table Rows' index starts at 0 and header row is deducted. 
(39-2)=37, the desired row index. ['K'] is column header (property name).
```

### Detail 3

[image]

### Final Output

[image]